# How to make Python.h file work in Ubuntu?

Tags: c, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04

I am on an Ubuntu machine and I want to use python in my C code but when I include the `Python.h` header file, it shows a warning:
`Python.h: No such file or directory`

Any method for this. I have already tried to use:

`sudo apt-get install python3-dev` and;

`sudo apt-get install python-dev`

But it keeps showing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python.h file is not in the default compiler include path.

Add the output of `pkg-config --cflags python3` to your compiler command line.

Now the compiler will know where to find Python.h (and any dependencies it may have)